# Is there a way to get a youtube ID for a song using ISRC?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've currently got a list of ISRCs (International Standard Recording Code which are unique identifiers for a song recording) and want to collect viewership count on youtube for that given song recording... I understand there's a way to query song statistics (such as viewership count, like count etc.) using the youtube API but this requires knowing the "youtube ID".

The way to get the youtube ID, according to my understanding, is by using the search feature in the youtube v3 API. However, there's no way to be definite that the search results for a song title will be an exact match to the song recording denoted by an ISRC. So, the question becomes - is there a way to get a youtube ID using a song's ISRC?

Comment: Please read **[ask]** , [edit] and improve your question

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Added details, please let me know what other insights I can provide.

Comment: Saad, thank you for edit your question. As far as I know, YouTube does not have any API or method(s) that meets your requirements, but, probably I'm wrong. I think it will improve even more the chances of receiving answers to your question if you share in your question what have you tried, what have you researched so far.

Comment: @SaadJeelani are you aware of any method to do the way around ? I mean getting the ISRC from a YouTube video ID ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list this should help - I was able to get the top trending, most popular and music videos charts which contain an ISRC as part of the "snippet" payload... You can try querying a single youtube ID - I believe you should be able to get the ISRC that way.

Comment: I am unable to retrieve Despacito's ISRC by using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,liveStreamingDetails,localizations,player,snippet,status&id=kJQP7kiw5Fk&key=API_KEY

Comment: Of course the ISRC won't be available for each song. It has to be manually entered by someone, and they won't always do that.